# How to attach pdf from trigger to an object?

Tags: pdf, triggers, salesforce, attachment

I'm a bit lost trying to attach a pdf with populated values from an opportunity record
Here is the code:

**Trigger**:

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert)
if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate) {
    opportunityTriggerHelper.attachFileToOpportunityRecord(trigger.new);
}
```

**Helper Class**:

```
private void attachFileToOpportunityRecord(List<Opportunity> lstOpp) {
    List<Id> oppListIdsForAttach = new List<Id>();

    for(Opportunity opp : lstOpp) {
        oppListIdsForAttach .add(opp.Id);
    }

    attachFileToOpportunities(oppListIdsForAttach);

}

@future(callout=true)
private static void attachFileToOppotunities(List<Id> OpportunityIds) {
    List<Attachment> attachList = new List<Attachment>();

    for(Id oppId : opportunityIds) {
        OpportunityPdfController file = new OpportunityPdfController();
        file.getData(oppId);
        PageReference pdfPage = Page.PdfAttachmentForOpp;
        blob pdfBody;
        pdfBody = pdfPage.getContent();

        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        attach.Body = pdfBody;
        attach.Name = 'Pdf file';
        attach.IsPrivate = false;
        attach.ParenId = oppId;

        attachList.add(attach);
    }
    insert attachList;
}
```

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="OpportunityPdfController" renderAs="pdf">

<apex:repeat value="{!pricingDetails}" var="pd">
    <apex:outputText>{!pd.basePrice}</apex:outputText>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

**VF Page Controller:**

```
public with sharing class OpportunityPdfController {
    public List<PricingDetailWrapper> pricingDetails {get;set;}

    public void getData(Id opportunityId) {
        List<Pricing_Detail__c> pdList = [
            SELECT basePrice
            FROM Pricing_Detail__c
            WHERE OpportunityId =: opportunityId
        ];
    
        for(Pricing_Detail__c pd : pdList) {

            PricingDetailWrapper pdw = new PricingDetailWrapper();
            pdw.basePrice = pd.basePrice;
    
            pricingDetails.add(pdw);
        }
    }

    public class PricingDetailWrapper {
        public String basePrice {get;set;}
    }
}
```

The result is whenever I update an opportunity it attaches the corresponding pdf file but it is blank and if I add for example the following to vf page body: `"<h1> hello World!</h1>"` this works and shows as expected, but this is not happening to what I required above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really pass the opportunity id to the VF page. And I doubt this actually works at all? If you manually access the VF page as `/apex/PdfAttachmentForOpp?id=006...` does it render the content ok? I'm assuming it doesn't.

**Fixing the page**

You didn't specify constructor so SF generates one for you, fine. I think you need to add something like

```
public OpportunityPdfController(){
    if(ApexPages.currentPage() != null){
        Id oppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        System.debug(oppId);
        getData(oppId);
    }
}
```

Add this, try to access the page passing valid opp id and see if it renders ok, if right stuff shows in debug log. `/apex/PdfAttachmentForOpp?id=006...`

(VF page constructors are bigger topic, this might be simpler with standardController + extension class)

**Fixing the callout**

VF page (especially accessed as callout) will not share memory with the `OpportunityPdfController` controller you've created in the code. New object of this class will be created to support the page and your `file` will be ignored. You might try to make-do with some static variable holding current opportunity's id but it feels bit yucky.

In normal execute anonymous try if this returns correct pdf:

```
PageReference pdfPage = Page.PdfAttachmentForOpp;
pdfPage.getParameters().put('id', '006...');
Blob pdfBody = pdfPage.getContent();
System.debug(pdfBody.toString());
```

If it works - use similar trick in the actual code, pass the id as url parameter.

Comment: Hello eyescream! Hope you are doing well, thanks for your answer, as you said the problem was that I wasn't passing the id parameter. I tried manually going to /apex/PdfAttachmentForOpp?id=006... and it renders ok, but isn`t working by executing the trigger. I guess is related from what you said about sharing memory but so far the error that i got is FATAL_ERROR System.VisualforceException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject" and "FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject" and that's because it's not sending the Id to the method.

Comment: what else is there in debug log, does it read the Id OK from the url or it comes empty? What if you System.debug(ApexPages.currentPage()); in the OpportunityPdfController's constructor?

Comment: You sure you didn't make "id" vs "Id" typos in the url param?

Comment: I just added the line you suggested `pdfPage.getParameters().put('id,oppId);` and it's working fine now, thanks for your help eyescream :)