# How to Invoke VF page render as PDF from batch Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

I want to call the vf page controller from an Batch apex. but i am getting the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqVbn.png)

**VF page controller**

public with sharing class QuoteToPDFControllerdownload {
....

public QuoteToPDFControllerdownload() {

```
}

public QuoteToPDFControllerdownload(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    
    quoteRecord = [
            SELECT ID, Name, OpportunityId, Status, Subtotal, Design_Basis__c, Exclusions__c,
                    Special_Notes__c, Account.Company__r.Address_1__c, Account.Company__r.Address_2__c,
                    Account.Company__r.Address_3__c, Account.Company__r.Address_4__c,Account.CustomerCodeIFS__c , Tax, Discount,
                    Global_Discount__c, Absolute_Discount__c, TotalPrice, Contact_Info__c,
                    Opportunity.Salesman__r.Name, Opportunity.Salesman__r.MobilePhone, Opportunity.Salesman__r.Email,
                    Opportunity.Company__r.Address_1__c, Opportunity.Company__r.Address_2__c,
                    Opportunity.Company__r.Address_3__c, Opportunity.Company__r.Address_4__c,
                    Opportunity.Company__r.Name, Opportunity.Company__r.Company__c,
                    Opportunity.New_Customer_Name__c,Opportunity.New_Customer_address__c,Opportunity.New_Customer_Address_2__c,Opportunity.New_Customer_Address_3__c, Opportunity.Name, Opportunity.CreatedDate
            FROM Quote
            WHERE Id = :controller.getId()
    ];
```

*String fileName = 'Quote_' + quoteRecord.Opportunity.Name + '.pdf';
ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
}*

**VF page**

<apex:page standardController="Quote" extensions="QuoteToPDFControllerdownload" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false"
applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" docType="html-5.0"
action="{! saveToPdf }" readOnly="false" renderAs="PDF">

.....

</apex:page>

**Batch Class**

public class QuoteToPDFBatchDownload implements Database.Batchable, Database.Stateful {

```
public Integer recordsProcessed = 0;
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
        SELECT ID, Opportunity_Number__c FROM Quote WHERE SentToIFS__c =TRUE    
    ]);
```

}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List scope){

```
    for (Quote qt : scope) {
        // PageReference pr = New PageReference('/apex/culliganReortDownload?id=' + qt.id ); 
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(qt);  
        QuoteToPDFControllerdownload qd = new QuoteToPDFControllerdownload(sc);
          recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;
    
}
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
     System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed. Ayesha!');
}
```

}

Comment: (shameless plug) Does this answer your question? [How to attach pdf from trigger to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68385363/how-to-attach-pdf-from-trigger-to-an-object). You need that `getParameters().put('id'` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you can try using the following statement, in Apex, in a custom controller, to access the **id** which you are passing via Batch class:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
```

Please let me know if it helps you out.

Thanks.